The seed entity for entity type 'IdentityUser' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'Id' when seeding default users
I'm trying to seed 2 default users (admin & standard user) using data migrations and I'm getting an error with the Id property of the IdentityUser entity.  This is the code I'm using:
internal sealed class IdentityUserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IdentityUser> builder)
    {
        Guid ADMIN_ID = new Guid("0007a13c-6a71-4c93-a7b9-35ea2ba6555e");
        Guid ADMIN_ROLE_ID = new Guid("2c5e174e-3b0e-446f-86af-483d56fd7210");
        Guid USER_ID = new Guid("8e445865-a24d-4543-a6c6-9443d048cdb9");
        Guid USER_ROLE_ID = new Guid("a6c43c31-811b-4c76-82a3-a65fd06078cd");


        //a hasher to hash the password before seeding the user to the db
        var hasherUser = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();
        var hasherAdmin = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();


        //Seeding the User to AspNetUsers table
        //admin
        builder.HasData(
            new IdentityUser
            {
                Id = ADMIN_ID.ToString(), // primary key
                ConcurrencyStamp = ADMIN_ROLE_ID.ToString(),
                UserName = "test@.com",
                NormalizedUserName = "TEST@TEST.COM",
                PasswordHash = hasherAdmin.HashPassword(null, "Pa$$w0rd")

            }
        );


        //Seeding the relation between our user and role to AspNetUserRoles table
        builder.HasData(
            new IdentityUserRole<string>
            {
                RoleId = ADMIN_ROLE_ID.ToString(),
                UserId = ADMIN_ID.ToString()
            }
        );


        //Seeding the User to AspNetUsers table
        //standard user
        builder.HasData(
            new IdentityUser
            {
                Id = USER_ID.ToString(), // primary key
                ConcurrencyStamp = USER_ROLE_ID.ToString(),
                UserName = "user@user.com",
                NormalizedUserName = "USER@USER.COM",
                PasswordHash = hasherUser.HashPassword(null, "Pa$$w0rd")
            }
        );


        //Seeding the relation between our user and role to AspNetUserRoles table
        builder.HasData(
            new IdentityUserRole<string>
            {
                RoleId = USER_ROLE_ID.ToString(),
                UserId = USER_ID.ToString()
            }
        );


    }
}

I've already created the roles using the same process which worked as expected however when I try to manually create the migrations I get this error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The seed
entity for entity type 'IdentityUser' cannot be added because no value
was provided for the required property 'Id'.' was thrown while
attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported
at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

A value is clearly provided for the Id property, so why won't this work? Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Do you have a full [mre]? Can you please share it?
